# Adding rows and finding the latest date for a particular column value in R

Tags: r

I have data like this.

```
Date        CIFNO   POS             POS CITY    NO OF TXNS  TXN.AMOUNT
1/5/2015    12000   Billdesk.com_   CRET         6           8,681.0
3/21/2014   12000   MTNL-BILLDESK   MUMBAI       1           556.0
2/1/2015    13000   bookmyshow      CRET         1           1,134.8
10/15/2013  12000   LUCKY           LUCKNOW      1           5,150.0
9/23/2015   13000   BASE PVT        KOLKATA      1           3,505.0
```

I needed to sum no of transactions and transaction amount for each CIF. Moreover, I also needed to keep the latest date of POS transaction and corresponding POS and POS city for each CIF. Essentially, I needed to get output like this:

```
Date        CIFNO   POS             POS CITY    NO OF TXNS  TXN.AMOUNT
1/5/2015    12000   Billdesk.com_   CRET        8           14,387.00
9/23/2015   13000   BASE PVT        KOLKATA     2           4,639.8
```

This adds no of transactions and trxn amount for CIF 12000 and 13000. It also takes the latest POS transaction date(1/5/2015 for CIF 12000 and 9/23/2015 for CIF 13000) and gets the corresponding POS and POS CITY for those latest dates for each CIF. Could anyone please help me on this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` you could do:

```
library(dplyr)
data$TXN.AMOUNT<-as.numeric(gsub(",","", data$TXN.AMOUNT))
data$Date <- as.Date(strptime(as.character(data$Date),"%m/%d/%Y"))

data%>% group_by(CIFNO) %>% arrange(Date) %>% summarise(Date=last(Date),
                                                    POS=last(POS),
                                                    POS.CITY=last(POS.CITY),
                                                    TXN.AMOUNT=sum(TXN.AMOUNT),
                                                    NO.OF.TXNS=sum(NO.OF.TXNS))
```

You get:

```
  CIFNO       Date           POS POS.CITY TXN.AMOUNT NO.OF.TXNS
1 12000 2015-01-05 Billdesk.com_     CRET    14387.0          8
2 13000 2015-09-23      BASE_PVT  KOLKATA     4639.8          2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Your solution is working for me..thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `data.table`. the following syntax gives you the result you need.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, Date := as.Date(strptime(as.character(Date),"%m/%d/%Y"))]
df[, TXN.AMOUNT := as.numeric(gsub(",","", TXN.AMOUNT))]

res <- df[order(-Date), .(Date=Date[1L],
                          POS=POS[1L],
                          POS.CITY=POS.CITY[1L],
                          NO.OF.TXNS=sum(NO.OF.TXNS),
                          TXN.AMOUNT=sum(TXN.AMOUNT)),
                         by = CIFNO]
setcolorder(res, c(2:1, 3:6))
```

we get the following result:

```
res
##          Date CIFNO           POS POS.CITY NO.OF.TXNS TXN.AMOUNT
## 1: 2015-09-23 13000      BASE.PVT  KOLKATA          2     4639.8
## 2: 2015-01-05 12000 Billdesk.com_     CRET          8    14387.0
```

---

Or a more robust solution

```
cols <- grep("TXN", names(df), value = TRUE)
df[order(Date), c(lapply(.SD[, cols, with = FALSE], sum),
                  lapply(.SD[, setdiff(names(.SD), cols), with = FALSE], last)), 
     by = CIFNO]
##    CIFNO NO.OF.TXNS TXN.AMOUNT       Date           POS POS.CITY
## 1: 12000          8    14387.0 2015-01-05 Billdesk.com_     CRET
## 2: 13000          2     4639.8 2015-09-23      BASE PVT  KOLKATA
```

Comment: Thanks David! you're syntax is brilliant. Notice that i've deffined Date to be of type 'Date'

Comment: Ok, added a more robust solution (I believe).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but none of these seem to be working for me..the first is giving lot of errors..when I tried using the second solution(robust one), it is deleting date and other columns..I don't know where I am going wrong..I am new to R..pls help..

Comment: you probably have an issue with the names of the clumns and the data type. see str(df). is  your 'transactions' of type 'fector'? they shouldn't be, they need to be num or int...

Comment: Thanks, I checked the datatype issues and then sorted with your help. But, the values I am getting are not what I wanted. The dates picked up are wrong and the sums are also wrong. Please let me know what I can do to resolve the issue.